# Hello I am trying to display "5 + 5 = 10" with the syntax as follows print ("2 + 2 = " + ( 2 + 2) )

Tags: python, explicit

I am trying to display `"5 + 5 = 10"` with the syntax as follows `print ("2 + 2 = " + ( 2 + 2) )`, what is the correct syntax to write it as i keep getting the error :

```
" TypeError: must be str, not int"
```

Appreciate the help :)

I tried : `str ("2 + 2 = " + ( 2 + 2) )`

Comment: try: `print("2 + 2 = " + str(2 + 2))`

Comment: ...and `5`s instead of the `2`s.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody suggested the f-strings:

```
print(f'2 + 2 = {2 + 2}')
```

Or even (since python3.8):

```
print(f'{2 + 2 = }')
```

Comment: a little more elegant:
result = 2 + 2;
print(f'2 + 2 = {result}')

Answer (score 2):

In python, it's different type,and you could not use + operator on type str and int.
for your case you can write below:

1.cover int to str:

```
"2 + 2 = " + str( 2 + 2)
```

2.use str.format method

```
"2+2={:d}".format(2+2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert `2+2` into a string before concatenating it to `"2+2"`.

```py
print("2 + 2 = "+str(2+2))
```

or even better, with f-strings

```py
print(f"2 + 2 = {2+2}")
```

If you want to avoid repeating the sum, you can use the `devtools` library (to be installed via `pip`)

```py
from devtools import debug

debug(f"{3+5=}")
```

```
>>> '3+5=8'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a string "2 + 2 =" to an int (4). Turn the int into a string first and then add the two strings together:

```py
"2 + 2 = " + str(2 + 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operand in python adds 2 items of the same type together - two strings join to become longer, or two numbers add to become a combined single number. Yuo are adding a string `"2+2="` to a number (2+2)=4, which doesn't make logical sense.

Either make both strings
`print ("2 + 2 = " + str( 2 + 2) )`

or rely on print to transform the numbers into strings for output, remove the `+` sign, and add a comma to show that you are printing two separate things.
`print ("2 + 2 = ", ( 2 + 2) )`